# Two-File PHP contact form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, contacts

pswThe index.php part seems to work fine, but the handler throws a internal server error (500).

index.php

```
    <div id="contact">
        <h1>Contact us</h1>
        <form id="ContactForm" method="post" action="submit.php">
            <p>
                <label>Name<span>(optional)</span></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" class="inplaceError" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="on"/>`enter code here`
                <span class="error" style="display:none;"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email<span>(optional)</span></label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Subject<span>(optional)</span></label>
                <input id="website" name="website" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Your message<br /> <span>700 characters allowed</span></label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="6" rows="5"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <input id="send" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
                <span id="loader" class="loader" style="display:none;"></span>
            </p>
    <input id="newcontact" name="newcontact" type="hidden" value="1"></input>
        </form>

submit.php -->


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $website = $_POST['website']; //subject
   $message = $_POST['message'];

   $connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "pswd") or die ('DB connection fail:' .mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db ("contactform");
   $query = "INSERT INTO contact (pk_contact, name, email, website, message, added_date)VALUES ('NULL','$name','$email','$sub','$msg','NULL')";
   //good to know about the quotes, but the page still insist there's an error
   mysql_query($query) or die ('Error uploading DB');
   mysql_close($connection);
   echo "<span id="success_message" class="success">YAY! It worked.</span>";
} else {
   echo "<span class='error'>Try again.</span>";
}
```

Comment: Check your logs, use PDO, read the FAQ.

Comment: You might want to remove your root password from the post.

Comment: @Mikecito, did you just blow our only in into the NSA?

Comment: Oh boy... sorry guys.  I'm sure they've changed it by now. :(

Comment: If you quote NULL, SQL will think you're trying to insert a string with the value of "NULL".  Remove the apostrophes and see what error it returns.

Comment: Is pk_contact the primary key of the table? I don't think you can insert NULL for the primary key. If you set it to autoincrement, you can just omit it from the query and I think you'll be ok. Updating my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got an error with your query string. It should look like

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, website, message, added_date)VALUES ('$name','$email','$sub','$msg',NULL)";
```

The double quotes were breaking up your string, and the different parts weren't being concatenated.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the primary key to my attention. I didn't think the problem was with the database, but once I added the primary and date columns with values of DEFAULT it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As Mikecito mentioned. You'll want to remove the quotes around NULL.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO contact (pk_contact, name, email, website, message, added_date)VALUES (NULL,'$name','$email','$sub','$msg',NULL)";
```

Assuming you have set you mysql table so the `added_date` field is a mysql timestamp format, attempting to enter `'NULL'` into the table will result in a mysql error.

Also make sure the mysql table allows null values to be entered into the `pk_contact` and `added_date` fields.